# bower_concat yields no output

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm completely new at Grunt, Bower etc. and have spent the evening playing around with a basic Gruntfile.js that contains the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        bower_concat: {
            all: {
                dest: 'assets/libs/<% pkg.name %>-bower.js',
                mainFiles: {
                    'flux': ['dist/Flux.js']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'bower_concat']);
};
```

However, when I run `grunt bower_concat` I get

```
Running "bower_concat:all" (bower_concat) task
Done, without errors.
```

but no JavaScript file is outputted in the destination folder (and I've tried running jshint, which does not complain).

I've tried lots of things, from e.g. removing mainFiles to including bowerOptions: { relative: false }.

The structure of my project is

- Web

  - assets

    - libs
  - bower_components

    - flux
  - node_modules

    - grunt
    - grunt-bower_concat
    - grunt-contrib-jshint
    - load-grunt-tasks

In the Web folder, I have bower.json, Gruntfile.js and package.json and it's from this folder that I run the command `grunt bower_concat`.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have the file bower_components/flux/dist/Flux.js? your gruntfile looks OK and works fine when I test it (besides a small fix - <%= pkg.name %>)

Comment: Thank you for the input! I just double checked and yes, I do have bower_components/flux/dist/Flux.js
Also, I tried to put another task in the Gruntfile.js:
  `concat: {
   options: {
    separator: ';'
   },
   dist: {
    src: ['bower_components/flux/dist/Flux.js', 'bower_components/react/react.js'],
    dest: 'assets/libs/all.js',
    nonull: true
   }`
and this works. Weird.